# 'find' equivalent function for char*

Tags: c++

I have the next code:

```
char * word = "?www?eee";
```

I wanto to see how many '?' I have . I know the that the "find" function works with string , and not with char*. is there an equivalent for char*?

thanks.

Comment: 1. Don't use `char*` unless interopping. 2. Don't assign string literals to `char*`.

Comment: You can easily generate a temporary string and use find on this string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) as:

```
size_t howMany = std::count(word, 
                            word + strlen(word), 
                            '?');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `std::count`:

```
std::size_t result = std::count(word, word + strlen(word), '?');
```

If you need a `find` function for some other purpose, there's `std::find`.

Answer (score -1):

You could also implement your own `find()-function`:

```
int find_char(char *str, char c) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(str[i] == c) {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You should prefer using existing STL functions than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Using `strlen` in the condition of the `for` loop has performance issues. I'd write `str[i] != '\0'` instead or storing the result of `strlen` to a temporary variable before the loop.

Comment: @Node what if the program is not otherwise using the STL? It's a good workable answer, with buc's proviso. The downvote is a bit harsh.

Comment: @acraig5075: if the program is not otherwise using the standard library, then it should start using it.

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel. If youre in c++ the std lib is available.